# In mongoose, how to initiate a model that having other model's reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

There is a model named User defined below.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');<br> var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({<br>
        firstName : {type: String, unique: false},<br>
        lastName : {type: String, unique: false},<br>
        loginName : {type: String, unique: true},<br>
        password : {type: String, unique: false},<br>
        email : {type: String, unique: false},<br>
        software: {<br>
            type : Schema.ObjectId,<br>
            ref  : Software<br>
        }<br>
});

module.exports  = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

When initiating an object of User, how to give value to "software" above?

```
var user1 = new User({<br>
        firstName: req.body.firstName,<br>
        lastName: req.body.lastName,<br>
        loginName: req.body.loginName,<br>
        password: req.body.password,<br>
        email: req.body.email,<br>
        ??????<br>
    });<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

just you send the  _id of software schema data from client,

like this `software : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb578"` (string only) then you get value using req.body.software

```
var user1 = new User({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        loginName: req.body.loginName,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body.email,
        software:req.body.software
    });
```

Comment: Better to name it req.body.softwareId

Comment: ya fin .. it your wish